# Generate a citable list of files in appendix

Tags: appendices, filesystem-access

In my overleaf project, I created an \appendix folder to store a lot of plots that should be in the appendix:

[image]

Is there a way to automatically create a citable list of the file names in that folder? Or do I have to create a large number of items and cite them manually ? They are subject to change during manuscript revision which will bring me a lot of trouble.